# Image from a font not drawn by Python

Tags: python, truetype

I wrote a Python script for drawing a character from a font, exporting, and sending it to a CGI interface for displaying. However, it isn't working. The code is as following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding: UTF-8
def getStringImage(text, font, size=40, color=[0,0,0]):
    import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
    img = Image.new("RGBA", (size, size), "white")
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw( img )
    draw.ink = color[0] + color[1]*256 + color[2]*256*256
    font = ImageFont.truetype(font, size)
    draw.text( (0,0), text, font=font )

    data = img.getdata()
    newData = list()
    for item in data:
        if (item[0], item[1], item[2]) == (255, 255, 255):
            newData.append((255, 255, 255, 0))
        else:
            newData.append((item[0], item[1], item[2], 255))
    img.putdata(newData)
    return img

text = ""  # U+E010
font = "hzcdp01b.ttf"
size = 100
color = [0, 0, 0]

img = getStringImage( text.decode('UTF-8'), font, size, color )
print 'Content-Type: image/png'
print 'Content-Disposition: inline; filename="image.png"'
print
import cStringIO
f = cStringIO.StringIO()
img.save(f, "png")
f.seek(0)
print f.read()
```

The font used above is extracted from this system: http://j.mp/14y6MAL, and here is the single backup file: http://j.mp/122PGLe

It works fine if another fonts is used (for example "mingliu.ttc" with char "人").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the character you want to display is actually mapped to a glyph. When looking at the `hzcdp01b.ttf`, it doesn't seem to have a character map table:

```
> fc-query hzcdp01b.ttf
Pattern has 15 elts (size 16)
    family: "hzcdp01b"(s)
    slant: 0(i)(s)
    weight: 80(i)(s)
    width: 100(i)(s)
    spacing: 100(i)(s)
    foundry: "unknown"(s)
    file: "hzcdp01b.ttf"(s)
    index: 0(i)(s)
    outline: FcTrue(s)
    scalable: FcTrue(s)
    charset: 
(s)
    lang: (s)
    fontversion: 69632(i)(s)
    fontformat: "TrueType"(s)
    decorative: FcFalse(s)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. It seems that the glyphs are somewhere in the file since this font is [viewable on the Windows after installed](http://ppt.cc/wQwg), and can be drawn with Visual Basic. Is there a way to map those useable glyphs into the font? And how?

Comment: @DannyLin: You would have to parse the `cmap` table inside the font. See e.g. [here](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=IWS-Chapter08) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TTRefMan/RM06/Chap6.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `python-fontbro` library (I'm the author of this lib) for generating a text image and much more very easily:

**Installation:**

```bash
pip install python-fontbro
```

**Usage:**

```py
from fontbro import Font

with Font("fonts/MyFont.ttf") as font:
    img = font.get_image(
        text="Hello!", 
        size=48, 
        color=(0, 0, 0, 255), 
        background_color=(255, 255, 255, 255),
    )
```

**Documentation**

Here there is the list of all available methods:

https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/python-fontbro#methods